# Symfony5 / Codeception: Service is not available in container

Tags: php, symfony, codeception, symfony5

**TL;DR**

In Codeception test I am trying to `$I->grabService()`. Service works in controllers and has no custom config, but I get:

`Fail  Service App\Service\Car is not available in container`

---

**Full Story**

I have a project with some `Services` which are basically classes, which do some processing. All the `Services` are accessible via service container. I am testing each class in functional suite (and some in unit) and everything worked fine till today.

So today I was adding a new Service and of course a test. I did:

```
root@9c80b567f681:/var/www/html# vendor/bin/codecept g:cest functional Service/Car
Test was created in /var/www/html/tests/functional/Service/CarCest.php
```

Test looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Service;

use App\Service\Car;
use App\Tests\FunctionalTester;

class CarCest
{
    public function _before(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->grabService(Car::class);
    }

    public function tryToTest(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
    }
}
```

Now I manually in PhpStorm create a new class. Class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

class Car
{

}
```

This is output of my testing:

```
root@9c80b567f681:/var/www/html# vendor/bin/codecept run tests/functional/Service/CarCest.php 
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.1.6
Powered by PHPUnit 9.2.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Running with seed: 


App\Tests.functional Tests (1) ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
✖ CarCest: Try to test (0.00s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 00:01.616, Memory: 34.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) CarCest: Try to test
 Test  tests/functional/Service/CarCest.php:tryToTest
 Step  Grab service "App\Service\Car"
 Fail  Service App\Service\Car is not available in container

Scenario Steps:

 1. $I->grabService("App\Service\Car") at tests/functional/Service/CarCest.php:12


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

TL;DR
**Fail  Service App\Service\Car is not available in container**

Now most of other tests I have use the same concept: I get service in `_before()` and then test it. Everything passes except of any class I add today :) WTF?!?

**BTW:** If I replace `$I->grabService(Car::class);` with any other service created before, it works fine.

My `services.yaml` is the standard, out-of-the-box Symfony version. I always relied simply on the fact everything in `src/*` is already a service.

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

I spent the whole morning installing/reinstalling/restarting PC... I am completely lost and stupid. Anybody has any idea ?

**EDIT:**

I noticed something very interesting. If I manually add the service to `services.yml` and set `public: true`, then I can use it from Codeception. But note, that I don't have to do this for any other services I created before.

Comment: why do you need to use `chown`? Is this Car class even visible to symfony/www-data? Try `php bin/console debug:container 'App\Service\Car'` or even `php bin/console debug:container` to see if it is even there. Try to use this service in regular code (in a controller for example) not in tests and see if it is even accesible.

Comment: @blahy Hi, thanks for your comment. Yes, I can use it from controller, I inject it via constructor and everything works. Also in `debug:container` / `debug:autowiring` I can see it correctly. All looks good.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your container? Also, have a look at the container directory itself - there should be some kind of "container build log" that might show information. For example, a service could be removed from the container if it is not used anywhere

Comment: @NicoHaase I guess you mean by cleaning `var/cache` ? I tried deleting whole directory and allowing Symfony to recreate. I also tried deleting whole project, pulling from git, and then reinstalling vendor etc. So `var` would be auto-recreated obviously. No joy.

Comment: And have you also checked the log of the container builder? In one of my projects, this is located at `var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainerCompiler.log` - this log might provide some insights about that given service

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, all looks exactly as for any other service. After more testing on the weekend it looks to me it may have something to do with codeception not being able to load this if it is not EXPLICITLY public. I added short `edit` about this.

Comment: I haven't used Codeception yet, but you could check which container is used - does it get the data from a container that uses the test environment? In Symfony's `KernelTestCase`, it uses a very specific test container where the services are `public` by default

Comment: @NicoHaase Codeception works similar, it has a special test container, so you can test even private services. I actually work with the person who wrote that in codeception :)

Comment: This also happens in **Symfony 4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR

Problem seems to be that Symfony removes all unused services upon container compilation. You can see the code [here on symfony project git page](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RemoveUnusedDefinitionsPass.php).

---

After I noticed, that my service works correctly when it's explicitly set to `public`, I started digging around that and I stumbled across [git issue](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/5828#issuecomment-595350301), where someone had the same problem. Some more digging (and talking to people smarten than me) got me to the link posted on top of this answer.

**BOOM!** Only took like 4 days...